# Db2 Pivot function - fetch next statement

Tags: sql, db2, pivot, db2-luw, bigsql

Under https://www.itjungle.com/2015/04/21/fhg042115-story01/ a good article on how to write an universal Db2 pivot method can be found.

Executing the following code (be aware of 'end #' instead 'end ;'):

```
SET SCHEMA = TESTSCHEMA;

CREATE PROCEDURE DO_PIVOT
(IN FOR_SCHEMA CHARACTER (10) , 
IN FOR_TABLE CHARACTER (10) , 
IN PIVOT_COLUMN VARCHAR (250) , 
IN VALUE_COLUMN VARCHAR (250) , 
IN AGG_FUNCTION VARCHAR (5) DEFAULT 'SUM' , 
IN GROUP_COLUMN VARCHAR (250) DEFAULT NULL ) 
LANGUAGE SQL 
MODIFIES SQL DATA 
PROGRAM TYPE SUB 
CONCURRENT ACCESS RESOLUTION DEFAULT 
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 
OLD SAVEPOINT LEVEL COMMIT ON RETURN NO 

BEGIN
DECLARE SQLCODE INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ;
DECLARE SQL_STATEMENT VARCHAR ( 5000 ) ;
DECLARE PIVOT_VALUE VARCHAR ( 20 ) ;
DECLARE PAD CHAR ( 2 ) DEFAULT ' ' ;
DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR D1 ;
DECLARE C2 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR D2 ;

SET SCHEMA = FOR_SCHEMA ;

-- Get the list of values available for the pivot column

-- Each value will be a column in the return set
SET SQL_STATEMENT = 'select distinct ' 
                   || PIVOT_COLUMN  
                   || ' from ' 
                   || FOR_TABLE 
                   || ' order by 1' ;

PREPARE D1 FROM SQL_STATEMENT ;
OPEN C1 ;

-- Construct a dynamic select statement for the pivot
SET SQL_STATEMENT = 'select ' ;

-- If requested, add the Group By Column 
-- to the select clause
IF GROUP_COLUMN IS NOT NULL THEN
  SET SQL_STATEMENT = SQL_STATEMENT || GROUP_COLUMN ;
  SET PAD = ', ' ;
END IF ;

-- For each possible value for the Pivot Column, 
-- add a case statement to perform the requested 
-- aggregate function on the Value Column
FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO PIVOT_VALUE ;
WHILE ( SQLCODE >= 0 AND SQLCODE <> 100 ) DO
  SET SQL_STATEMENT = SQL_STATEMENT 
                      || PAD 
                      || AGG_FUNCTION 
                      || '(CASE WHEN ' 
                      || PIVOT_COLUMN 
                      || ' = ''' 
                      || PIVOT_VALUE 
                      || ''' THEN ' 
                      || VALUE_COLUMN 
                      || '  END) AS ' 
                      || PIVOT_VALUE ;
  SET PAD = ', ' ;
  FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO PIVOT_VALUE ;
END WHILE ;
CLOSE C1 ;

-- Specify the table to select from
SET SQL_STATEMENT = SQL_STATEMENT 
                    || ' from ' 
                    || FOR_TABLE ;

-- If requested, add the Group By Column
-- to the select clause
IF GROUP_COLUMN IS NOT NULL THEN
  SET SQL_STATEMENT = SQL_STATEMENT 
                      || ' group by ' 
                      || GROUP_COLUMN 
                      || ' order by ' 
                      || GROUP_COLUMN;
END IF ;

PREPARE D2 FROM SQL_STATEMENT ;
OPEN C2 ;

END #

LABEL ON ROUTINE DO_PIVOT 
( CHAR(), CHAR(), VARCHAR(), VARCHAR(), VARCHAR(), VARCHAR() )  
IS 'Perform a General Purpose Pivot';

COMMENT ON PARAMETER ROUTINE DO_PIVOT 
( CHAR(), CHAR(), VARCHAR(), VARCHAR(), VARCHAR(), VARCHAR() ) 
(FOR_SCHEMA IS 'Schema for Table' , 
FOR_TABLE IS 'For Table' , 
PIVOT_COLUMN IS 'Name of Column to be Pivoted' , 
VALUE_COLUMN IS 'Column to be Aggregated for Pivot' , 
AGG_FUNCTION IS 'Use Aggregate Function' , 
GROUP_COLUMN IS 'Group on Column' ) ;
```

produces the error message:

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was
not a valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it
returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "FROM" was found following "    FETCH
NEXT".
Expected tokens may include:  ".".  LINE NUMBER=50.  SQLSTATE=42601
```

- the procedure seems to be programmed for an older Db2 Version possibly on iSeries
- regarding the present LUW Version (10.5, 11.1), the syntax for the "fetch next" in the code snippet seems correct at first glance: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000954.html
- tested on Db2 Big SQL 4.2 ("DB2 v11.1.0.0", "s160705", "BSQL160705AMD64", and Fix Pack "0")

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show parameters of call.  Thanks in advance

Comment: like on the linked page: CALL DO_PIVOT('SQLSTAND',              'SALES','SALES_PERSON', 'SALES', DEFAULT, DEFAULT); - see also the documentation of the parameters. Aggregation function works, but is not so comfortable for more complex aggregates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Db2-LUW v11.1 and above, to get the sproc to compile, you can make the changes listed below. This is only for getting a successful compile. I've not checked the functionality.

- Remove (or comment-out) PROGRAM TYPE SUB
- Remove (or comment-out)    CONCURRENT ACCESS RESOLUTION DEFAULT
- Change FETCH NEXT FROM  to      FETCH  (in two places) , or use FETCH FROM
- Remove (or comment-out) LABEL ON ROUTINE    statement
- Remove (or comment-out) COMMENT ON PARAMETER ROUTINE    statement

Comment: thanks a lot - excellent. Can you provide details how to know the solution for point no.3 (the other points found also myself) - just reading https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000954.html

Comment: Db2-LUW FETCH in static-SQL is functionally equivalent to FETCH NEXT.  Syntax variations between Db2 platforms (LUW, iSeries, Z/OS) is common.